# Where can we find the registry enteries of soapui

Tags: registry, soapui

I want to check if the following settings in soapui can be changed via registries changes.
File - Preferences - Editor Settings

If anyone can help me in finding the registry entries for the same.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the people use soap-UI as a stand alone application and it don't have anything to do with the registry settings.

Regarding your question, "File - Preferences - Editor Settings"

Your Editor Settings will be saved in a XML file named "**soapui-settings.xml**".
You can find this file under "**C:\Users\**" directory.

Comment: To add: SoapUI is a platform-independent Java application. Most OSes do not have anything like a registry.